# Create common class, has dependency, how do I formally share this dependency?

Tags: java, json, maven, dependencies, mule

I've extended an abstract class and implemented a method that I will use with Mule over and over. I want to add it to a library that I will repo on Maven central. It depends on a JAR that's provided in the Mule connector devkit (sdk for Mule connectors). How do I formally publish or tell others publicly that my common library will not work without the earlier dependency too? The dependencies org.json and fasterXML...Jackson..etc.

My code module is an HttpProcessMessage and the over-used method returns a String of formatted JSON. The message POJO gets loaded and then ultimately my method is like a toString() method but more sophisticated.

I would like for this class to be part of a common library that would become part of the community. I wish that my code here would be the foundation and have no dependencies. Now, I'm looking for an answer to address the dependencies and inform the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the main benefits of Maven and other dependency management tools, when your dependency is added to their Maven project, Maven will automatically fetch transitive dependencies. So there is no need to let people know what dependencies you rely on. It will automatically be handled and they can use Maven command if they wish or inspect the maven artefact to determine what transitive dependencies you rely on.

You will need to add the com.faster.xml dependencies and org.json dependencies to your Maven pom.xml and all this information is packaged alongside your Maven artefact and will be stored in a Maven repo.

More info on Maven dependencies here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

If they are manually installing the jar outside of Maven/Gradle etc. then theres not much you can do except provide them a detailed README on installation instructions.

Comment: Perfect! The addition of the dependency in the Maven POM will be evident when I isolate my work into a Maven project with JAR packaging. The red-X'es in Eclipse or similar will tell me that.  And, I think Maven is the best way to handle my common code. Thanks!